# No separators in certain Analytics API metrics output

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've started using the Analytics API since a little while, and I noticed that some metrics are a bit off in the output. For example, I'd expect the ga:adCost metric to give me numbers such as 55.96, while it produces something like 55961449. So it doesn't provide the period (or comma).

The same is true for other (mostly calculated) metrics, such as ga:CPC, ga:pageviewsPerSession, ga:avgTimeOnPage and ga:avgSessionDuration.

What my output looks like.

[image: What my output looks like]

Then there's also other metrics (such as ga:timeOnPage and ga:sessionDuration) which put ".0" behind every number. Since we use comma's instead of periods in my language, I have to use Excel formulas to convert all these periods into comma's before I'm able to use these numbers in my calculations. I was wondering if there's a workaround for this too.

Thanks for reading and hopefully one of you has a solution for (one of) these issues!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with Analytics but it depends on your Excel settings and/or your computer settings.